# parsing location.search object to find query params

Tags: javascript-objects, google-chrome-console

I'm trying to figure out where in the `location.search object` the *query params* are:

Code:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
console.log(params);
```

URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/detail/8?abc=20
```

Chrome Console:

[image]

- Where should I traverse to find `params` in the `URLSearchParams object` tree in the Console?
- Also is there a find or search feature in the Console that lets me figure out the location of something? It's like an endless tree.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of accessing the parameters via the API, I'm guessing `get`, `getAll`, or `keys` are what you need. The reason you don't see values directly in the console is that these are methods, not attributes, so they need to be executed for you to see the actual data.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

This question isn't really a ReactJS question, unless you're having trouble with the `this.props.location.search` object itself, in which case you should post its source/parent component.

Comment: Thanks -- I removed the `reactjs` tag.